# Is backlinking to yourself in violation of Google's guidelines?

Tags: google, backlinks

Many people say that setting up your own backlinks is not good. Is this true?

Nobody can expect backlinks to be built by other sites naturally unless they are social networking sites or some good topic. Even the top news sources won't have backlinks naturally.

Google doesn't know these, so can we build backlinks ourself?

Answer (score 1):

Any links intended to manipulate PageRank or a site's ranking in Google search results may be considered part of a link scheme and a violation of Google’s Webmaster Guidelines. This includes any behavior that manipulates links to your site or outgoing links from your site.

To understand google and backlinks here's a [**great start.**](https://blog.monitorbacklinks.com/seo/types-backlinks-violating-googles-guideliness/)

Further reading **[here.](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35769)**

Comment: you are saying what i already know,the question here as a webmaster can i myself partcipate in link building for my website or else only other webmasters need to link naturally?